# Influxdb Numbered Tag Sort

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I am using Influxdb with Grafana and Telegraf.

With the following Query in Influxdb:

```
  show tag values from myTable with key = myInd
```

And the Result is

```
    key value
    --- -----
   myInd    0
   myInd    1
   myInd    10
   myInd    11
   myInd    2
```

How do I get the sorting to display this in order `0, 1, 2` instead of `0,1,10,11,2` ?

This will also me with my Grafana table to sort it the columns in serie when I use Group by myInd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Influxdb uses the tags as String and therefore are sorted as Strings.